# How to draw two JPanels on top of each other?

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working on a **N-Body simulation** and I have made particles move on a black screen. My current problem is that there is no way of controlling it.

##### My plan:

[image]

Each color stands for a different `JPanel`. The blue one should contain the buttons and text fields, the red one the viewport.

But with my small knowledge in Java, I didn't succeed in creating this. I first tried with `setBounds` and `setLayoutManager(null)`, in vain.

My structure goes like that:

- `Window` class extends `JFrame`
- `Simulation` class creating `blueJPanel` class (extends `JPanel`) and `redJPanel`,
- adds them to the window.

But this is garbage code... So how would you draw these simple panels on top of each other?

Comment: One `JPanel` is above the other.  "On top" implies they occupy part of the same 2D plane.  English aside, create two `JPanels`, one blue and one red.  A `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`, so place the blue `JPanel` in NORTH and the red `JPanel` in CENTER.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: Hello, English is not my main language so... Im gonna try your tip! Currently Im confused about all these layout managers because they are all so different etc

Comment: *they are all so different* - that is the point, they should be different because they provide a different layout. You use the layout or combination of layouts that allows you to achieve your desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

As I said in my comment, you create two `JPanels`.  Here's an example.

[image: Example]

Here's the complete runable code to create this example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BorderLayoutExampleGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BorderLayoutExampleGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BorderLayout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);

        // Add the buttons and text fields

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 380));
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);

        // Add the drawing code

        return panel;
    }

}
```